# Why "opener.$(document).trigger('custom')" is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

I want to implement simple pub/sub pattern with jQuery. 
So I add some code like this on parent page:

Parent page:

```
$(document).bind('custom', function() { ... });
```

And it's working fine when I trigger on same page like this:

Same Page:

```
$(document).trigger('custom');  // Working.
```

But when I trigger this on popup page, it's not working.

Popup page:

```
opener.$(document).trigger('custom');  // Not working.
$(opener.document).trigger('custom');  // Not working.
```

If I bind event to `<body>` element, it works find.

Parent Page:

```
$('body').bind('custom', function() { ... });
```

Popup Page:

```
opener.$('body').trigger('custom');  // Working.
```

Why binding to `document` is not working on Popup?

Comment: I think because if you do that from the parent page you use the `document` variable from the parent page. What happens if you do `opener.$(opener.document).trigger('custom');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @11684 said, the answer to make it work is:

```
opener.$(opener.document).trigger('custom');
```

The @Rory's answer:

```
$(opener.document).trigger('custom');
```

is not working because the popup's `$` doesn't have the event handler of `opener.document`.

And this one:

```
opener.$(document).trigger('custom');
```

is not working because the `document` is popup's `document` so it's different from the `opener.document`.

And lastly,

```
opener.$('body').trigger('custom');
```

is working because the opener's `$` has event handler and the argument(`body`) is just string(not a object like `document`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the whole `opener.document` in to a jQuery object. Try this in the popup:

```
$(opener.document).trigger('custom');
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work. `opener.$(opener.document).trigger` is working.